# How do I refresh a component by clicking button of another component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, react-component

**Current Flow of Application**
[image]
**Navbar Component code**

```
export default function Navbar() {
  const [noOfWislistedProducts, setnoOfWislistedProducts] = useState(0);
  function fetchNumberOfItemsInWishlist() {
    const noOfItems =
      localStorage.getItem("products").split(",")
        .length - 1;
    setnoOfWislistedProducts(noOfItems);
  }
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchNumberOfItemsInWishlist();
  }, [noOfWislistedProducts]);
  return (
      <AppBar color="inherit" position="fixed">
          <NavLink
            exact
            to={"/products/wishlisted"}
            activeClassName="activeClass"
            style={{ color: "Black", paddingRight: "10px" }}
          >
            <Button color="inherit" variant="contained">
               Wishlist {noOfWislistedProducts}
            </Button>
          </NavLink>
  );
```

**Wislisted Products Component code**

[image]
[image]

**Now  how do I force navbar to refresh everytime when a delete button is clicked inside wishlisted component .?**

Comment: send the click event to the other component or use ref

Answer (score 1):

You can make a parent component containing all logic to remove and add nodes. Make children as just view components not for rendering Ui through props. You pass the click handlers and data as props for children.
Calls this handlers from children and use the data to render.